# Is there alternative to node js websocket?

Tags: javascript, php, html, node.js, websocket

I'm trying to use web-sockets for developing a web aplication. How to launch websocket server without running second aplication like NodeJS? We are using an online shared server.

Comment: You could use [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) which is a PHP implementation of web sockets. You'd still need to be able to set it up to run on the server though. It's been a long time since I used shared hosting - but if they are anything like before I'm not sure how suitable they are to run applications depending on sockets.

Answer (score 0):

any back-end language can do that, for php u can refer http://socketo.me/, through i don't really know it

and php swoole i think